# Angular ngFor and CSS Grid - how to detect first column?

Tags: angular, css-grid

I am trying to use ngFor with CSS crid. However, for the first column I need to be make div element and color it.

Any ideas how I can test if it's the first column in a css grid with `ngFor`?

```
            <div  class="grid">

              <span scope="col">EXAMPLE</span>
              <span scope="col">VALUE</span>
              <span scope="col">TOKEN</span>
              <span scope="col">STATUS</span>

              <span *ngFor="let token of tokens">
                <div
                  class="color-box"
                  [style.backgrouncolor]="token"
                  *ngIf="token === <first column>; else showString">
                </div>
                <span #showString>{{token}}</span>
              </span>

            </div>
```

```
export class ColorsComponent {
  private tokenMap: Array<object> = [
    {
      example: '#0075DE',
      value: '#0075DE',
      name: '$ws-big-stone-A700',
      status: 'good',
    },
    {
      example: '#0075DE',
      value: '#0075DE',
      name: '$ws-big-stone-A700',
      status: 'good',
    },
    {
      example: '#0075DE',
      value: '#0075DE',
      name: '$ws-big-stone-A700',
      status: 'good',
    },
    {
      example: '#0075DE',
      value: '#0075DE',
      name: '$ws-big-stone-A700',
      status: 'good',
    },
  ];

  tokens = this.tokenMap.map(e => (
    Object.values(e).map(e => e)
  )).flat();
```

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.grid > span {
  padding: 8px 4px;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a check if your current element index `i` is a multiple of `4`. Combining the answer from @Derek.W (thank you), this should work:

```
<span *ngFor="let token of tokens; let i = index">
    <div class="color-box"
         [style.backgrouncolor]="token"
         *ngIf="i % 4 === 0; else showString">
    </div>
    <span #showString>{{token}}</span>
</span>
```

Also you can achieve that by manually parsing CSS properties directly from the grid container element using specific libraries (you can definitely do that with `jQuery`).

I'm afraid, there are no other tools to do such things right in the `ngFor` directive.

Answer (score 1):

On `ngFor`, you can get index of each item as follows.

```
*ngFor="let token of tokens; let i = index"
```

So you can determine if it's the first element or not using `i` value.
If `i == 0`, it's first element.